# Gradle build not working for React Native project after updating Gradle version and Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I'd looked through similar questions on here but I haven't found any that worked for me so far.

#### Problem

I recently updated Android studio to the version below:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034, built on November 21, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.0.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 4
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
```

After doing this, I somehow managed to update the `Android Gradle Plugin Version` to `4.1.3` and `Gradle Version` to `6.9` under File > Project Structure > Project.

After doing this, a Gradle sync was triggered and it was successful but there were these warnings:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.5.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.5.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.5.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.75.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:2.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.12.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

And when I try to run the app on an emulator, the Gradle build fails with these errors:

```
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug

FAILURE: Build completed with 18 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
         project :app > project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage
         project :app > project :react-native-community_clipboard
         project :app > project :react-native-masked-view_masked-view
         project :app > project :react-native-email-link
         project :app > project :react-native-encrypted-storage
         project :app > project :react-native-gesture-handler
         project :app > project :react-native-pager-view
         project :app > project :react-native-safe-area-context
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
         project :app > project :react-native-svg
         project :app > project :react-native-vector-icons
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.20.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :unimodules-core
         project :app > project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
         project :app > project :expo-constants
         project :app > project :expo-haptics
         project :app > project :expo-local-authentication
         project :app > project :expo-localization
         project :app > project :expo-modules-core
         project :app > project :unimodules-app-loader
         project :app > project :unimodules-task-manager-interface
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo-constants
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.6.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo-constants
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-pager-view
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.20.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-encrypted-storage > androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens > androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
         project :app > project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage
         project :app > project :react-native-community_clipboard
         project :app > project :react-native-masked-view_masked-view
         project :app > project :react-native-email-link
         project :app > project :react-native-encrypted-storage
         project :app > project :react-native-gesture-handler
         project :app > project :react-native-pager-view
         project :app > project :react-native-safe-area-context
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
         project :app > project :react-native-svg
         project :app > project :react-native-vector-icons
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.20.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :unimodules-core
         project :app > project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
         project :app > project :expo-constants
         project :app > project :expo-haptics
         project :app > project :expo-local-authentication
         project :app > project :expo-localization
         project :app > project :expo-modules-core
         project :app > project :unimodules-app-loader
         project :app > project :unimodules-task-manager-interface
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo-constants
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.6.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo-constants
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-pager-view
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.20.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-encrypted-storage > androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens > androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
         project :app > project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage
         project :app > project :react-native-community_clipboard
         project :app > project :react-native-masked-view_masked-view
         project :app > project :react-native-email-link
         project :app > project :react-native-encrypted-storage
         project :app > project :react-native-gesture-handler
         project :app > project :react-native-pager-view
         project :app > project :react-native-safe-area-context
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
         project :app > project :react-native-svg
         project :app > project :react-native-vector-icons
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.20.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :unimodules-core
         project :app > project :unimodules-react-native-adapter
         project :app > project :expo-constants
         project :app > project :expo-haptics
         project :app > project :expo-local-authentication
         project :app > project :expo-localization
         project :app > project :expo-modules-core
         project :app > project :unimodules-app-loader
         project :app > project :unimodules-task-manager-interface
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:2.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo-constants
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.6.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo-constants
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-pager-view
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.20.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.google.crypto.tink:tink-android:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-encrypted-storage > androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha03
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.30.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-screens > androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unimodules-core:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':unimodules-core:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.21.
     Required by:
         project :unimodules-core
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

5: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.12.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.5.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_clipboard:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_clipboard:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_clipboard > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-community_clipboard > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

7: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-email-link:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-email-link:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-email-link > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-email-link > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

8: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-encrypted-storage:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-encrypted-storage:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.yoga:proguard-annotations:1.14.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-encrypted-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.0.3.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-encrypted-storage > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.1
      > Skipped due to earlier error
      > Skipped due to earlier error
```

I couldn't make any sense of the errors myself, I'm thinking that I need to update all the dependencies (react-native packages) that are listed in these Gradle builds?

#### Here's more information:

- React Native version: `0.64.1`.
- Root-level `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

content of `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
#Wed Jan 12 19:07:20 WAT 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

content of `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.75.1
```

Comment: I just posted a similar question for my flutter app, and I am starting to think that one of the remote repository servers is down or something.

Comment: That sounds like a plausible explanation @Scorb, maybe I'll try again in a few hours.

Comment: jcenter has been sunset. So you have to update your dependencies to find out which one is still using jcenter, and hope a new version fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though its marked deprecated and sunset, jcenter will remain a read depo indefinitely. It could be that your dependency is on bintray or possibly that gradle itself has dropped support. You might need to find an alternative.

https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

UPDATE: JFrog has decided to keep JCenter as a read-only repository indefinitely. New package and versions are no longer accepted on JCenter. All Bintray services have been shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [medium article](https://medium.com/@emailoflala/bintray-service-down-and-package-build-failed-to-list-versions-of-react-native-d48146790fd5) and moved `jcenter()` to the bottom of `repositories {}` in `.\android\build.gradle`

These solved my issue. Hope it works for you.
Thanks